# Error in AJAX code causing broswer to crash

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I have written an ajax script that grabs different pages and displays them for X amount of time and then switches to the next page. I use the setTimeout function to display the pages for the X amount of time. In order to grab each page I created a list of different pages in a database that my code looks at then calls the appropriate php function to grab the data.

What seems to be happening is that it causes firefox to crash after a couple of days because firefox seems to run out of memory. My guess is that my code is not efficient but, I am not sure how I can make it more efficient so it does not crash the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<div id="result">
</div>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer');?>

<?php $displayName = $this->input->get('name');?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var views = [];
var cell = '';
var i = 0;
var display = <?php echo json_encode($displayName); ?>;
var timeOut = 0;

$(function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "get_display_data/"+display,
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       views = JSON.parse(data);
      if (i >= views.display.length) {
          i = 0;
      } else if (views.display[i].view == 'Fabrication') {
               var loadUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Cells/FabricationStatus/"+views.display[i].view + "/"+ "display1?name="+display;
               $("#result").empty().load(loadUrl+"#mainContent");
               timeOut = 60;
               i++;
      } else if(views.display[i].view == 'CYLPLNGLCMSH') {
               var loadUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Cells/CYLPLNGLCMSHStatus/"+views.display[i].view + "/"+display; 
               $("#result").empty().load(loadUrl+"#mainContent");
               timeOut = 60;
               i++;
      } else if(views.display[i].view == 'COTCTR') {
               var loadUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Cells/COTCTRStatus/"+views.display[i].view + "/"+display;
               $("#result").empty().load(loadUrl+"#mainContent");
               timeOut = 60;
               i++;
      } else {
              var loadUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Cells/Display/"+views.display[i].view + "/"+display;
             $("#result").empty().load(loadUrl+".mainContent");
              timeOut = 30;
              i++;
      }
       setTimeout(get_data, (1000 * timeOut));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You want to display those data in your browser or save them in your DB?

Comment: You could try saving some information to, say, the session then refresh the page. Every refresh you load a new page.

Comment: Not then solution, but you can shorten this line

var display = <?php echo json_encode($displayName); ?>;

to 

var display = "<?=json_encode($displayName)?>";

Also good to wrap in quotes.

Comment: @satafaka I want to display the data in the browser.

Comment: @MikeC Are you saying save the results and check to see if there have been any changes to the data and if so refresh the page otherwise keep displaying the saved results?

Comment: @RizwanChaudry Sure, if you want. I'm not saying save the results at all though. I'm saying you just refresh the whole page and the server will automatically display the next result. Whether that be because you sent along a GET variable, stored something in the session, or whatever else.

Comment: You have to use jQuery ? Maybe it works better with native javascript ajax calls or a different framework ? (GoogleClosure?)

Comment: @MikeC Im not sure if I can do that. If I were to refresh the whole page the page carousel would start back up on the first page and not on the page it had been on before. I have a windows service that grabs data from a sql server and copies it over to a mysql database every 30 mins. I apologize I am still not totally understanding what you mean. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: @Meffen No worries! :

Comment: I think its the method "empty()" which only remove the html from DOM, but not out of the memory. I tested with a loop (no ajax):
html = '<h1>Some html</h1>... PUT MORE HTML HERE TO TEST';
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { $('#result').empty().html(html);  }
My memory increase to > 2 GB after time. I dont know how to fix this with pure jQuery.

Comment: @Meffen thanks for looking into that I appreciate it! Ill dig deeper into it!